# EJS templating language internal logic fails somehow

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm using EJS partials and I just meet a bug that I couldn't figure out at all even after wasting hours of debuging...

Here is the code to load the partial:

```
<%- partial(__view.partialPath('tag_popover'), {
    title_popover: sentence.nickname,
    content_tag: '#' + sentence.nickname,
    icon_popover: 'http://placehold.it/64x64'
}) %>

<%- partial(__view.partialPath('tag_popover'), {
    title_popover: 'Last revision',
    content_tag: '#' + sentence.sentenceId
}) %>
```

Here is the `tag_popover` partial:

```
<%
/**
 * Creates a standalone tag with dynamic title, content and popover for additional content.
 *
 * @param classes_tag       CSS classes. ['tags']
 * @param content_tag       Tag content.
 * @param icon_popover      Popover icon. [none]
 * @param title_popover     Popover title, will be displayed.
 */

title_popover = typeof title_popover != 'undefined' ? title_popover : ''
classes_tag = typeof classes_tag != 'undefined' ? classes_tag : 'tags'
icon_popover = typeof icon_popover != 'undefined' ? icon_popover : false
content_tag = typeof content_tag != 'undefined' ? content_tag : ''
%>

<li class="<%= classes_tag %>" title="<%= title_popover %>">
    <a href="#"><%= content_tag %></a>
    <%- partial(__view.partialPath('popover_revision_translation'), {
        icon_popover: icon_popover
    }) %>
</li>
```

And finally the `popover_revision_translation` partial:

```
<%
/**
 * Creates a standalone popover with dynamic title and body.
 *
 * @param icon_tag   Icon. [none]
 */
icon_popover = typeof icon_popover != 'undefined' ? icon_popover : ''
%>
<% console.log('--------------------------'+typeof icon_popover)%>
<% console.log(icon_popover ? true: false)%>

<div class="custom-popover-content hide" role="seealso">
    <% if(icon_popover){ %>
        <img src='<%= icon_popover%>' />
    <% } %>
    <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

So basically, I call twice my `tag_popover` partial, once with a `icon_popover` set and once with no `icon_popover`. But it display twice an icon, on the first element but also on the second, where I didn't want any.

So, I put some `console.log` in the `popover_revision_translation` to help me to understand what's going on, since I asked the icon to be rendered only if set, and setting it to `false` if undefined: `icon_popover = typeof icon_popover != 'undefined' ? icon_popover : false`.

Here are the server logs:

```
--------------------------string
true
--------------------------boolean
false
```

So basically whether it is a `string` or a `false`, it goes into my `if` statement `<% if(icon_popover){ %>` and I can't figure out why.

I made more test, like `<% if(icon_popover !== false){ %>` or `<% if(icon_popover === 'http://placehold.it/64x64'){ %>`and in both cases I met the same results.

So I really don't get it and I think it may be related to some EJS internal issues or caching, but anyway it's really weird that the logs shows something which seems logical but doesn't act that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That had nothing to do with EJS failure, it was actually because of a javascript dynamic parsing that always took the first element, which had the icon. The generated source code was right, but its use wasn't and always displayed the same.

No dark magic here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a scope issue. I don't know the details of your tool chain, but probably the "parameters" are either in the global name space or in a common name space. Check your documentation to see how to create local variables (or perhaps it's not possible.) If you can't find anything else, try putting `var` in front of each definition, e.g.

```
var title_popover = typeof title_popover != 'undefined' ? title_popover : '';
var classes_tag = typeof classes_tag != 'undefined' ? classes_tag : 'tags';
var icon_popover = typeof icon_popover != 'undefined' ? icon_popover : false;
var content_tag = typeof content_tag != 'undefined' ? content_tag : '';
```

I don't know for sure if that will work because I don't know EJS, but it's a guess worth trying.

Comment: I tried that already, and if I do so, then it kills the parameters, because somehow it set the `title_popover` before to load it, like if it read the code from left to right instead of the traditionnal right to left. So i end up with empty vars...
I also thought it was a scope issue, but what's weird is that it logs correctly what I expect, but it doesn't act like it.